# Enable span onclick inside asp link button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

On our webpage we have a search that loads a list of events based on whether they are open or closed events. Each event has its own ID. When the events load it is a block with event name, date, the event administrators name all inside an asp:LinkButton that fires off a javascript post back. If you click anywhere inside this block it loads quick information about the event.

What I am trying to accomplish is if the event is open, place a link inside of the asp:LinkButton that will take the user to the event's details page. Knowing that I cannot nest  tags, but the clients requirements request the link being inside the same block.

This is an example of a closed event. This works fine:

```
<div id="EventList">
    <a id="EventList_lnkEventListItem_0" class="list-item show-overlay" href="javascript:__doPostBack()">
        <span class="event-date col-md-48 col-sm-48">
            02/02/2017                                        
        </span>                                    
        <span class="event-name col-md-48 col-sm-48"></span> 
        <span class="EventCoordinator-name col-md-48 col-sm-48">
            Started by: Me 
        </span>
        <div class="col-md-48 text-sm">
            Status: Closed
        </div>

        <br class="list-item-clear" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This is an example of an open event that I need the link in, I've added a span showing an example:

```
<div id="EventList">
    <a id="EventList_lnkEventListItem_0" class="list-item show-overlay" href="javascript:__doPostBack()">
        <span class="event-date col-md-48 col-sm-48">
            02/02/2017                                        
        </span>                                    
        <span class="event-name col-md-48 col-sm-48"></span> 
        <span class="EventCoordinator-name col-md-48 col-sm-48">
            Started by: Me 
        </span>
        <span class="startedby-name col-md-48 col-sm-48" onclick="window.open(/events/scheduledevents?eventid=####, '_blank')">
            Open Event in New Window
        </span>

        <div class="col-md-48 text-sm">
            Status: Open
        </div>

        <br class="list-item-clear" />                                    
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I get the asp variable for the event id into the onclick event? Is there a better way to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stopPropagation() will prevent any parent handlers beeing notified. You can try like this:

```js
function parentFunction(){
  console.log('parent fired');
}

function childFunction(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation(); // you can comment this line and see the difference
  console.log('child fired');
}
```

```css
$('.item-button').click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="parentFunction();">
  Lorem ipsum
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span onclick="childFunction(event);">
    Child button
    </span>
  
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Still parent
  </a>
```

Comment: The propagation isn't what's stopping me necessarily. I can't get the event Id into the onclick event.

Comment: @jcalton88 if i understood it correctly, you need ItemTemplate. This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336785/asp-net-gridview-itemtemplate

Comment: Thanks. I was already using an itemtemplate.  It was an unexpected issue with placement within the template.  I'll post an answer with exactly what fixed it. However, since the stoppropagation and the comment about itemtemplate was the answer (and my implementation was incorrect) I'm marking this as the answer.